# Where can we use conditional clearance?

Tags: air-traffic-control, icao-sarps, clearance

Besides Line up conditional clearance in a PREPARATION FOR TAKE-OFF situation, where else can we use conditional clearance (on an apron, taxiway, etc.)?

Comment: I am interested in ICAO STANDARD.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation! Please feel free to [edit] your question to indicate the ICAO standards detail - not everyone will read the comments before answering, and comments can get deleted. While you're at it, please take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you can make the best of this Q&A web site!

Answer (score 1):

Conditional clearances can be issued for any stage of flight, but are usually not as they increase risk outside of the areas that you have listed.

In the en route environment a controller can issue conditional climb instructions for example:

`SIA1223 at DOGET climb to FL340`

`BAW2283 passing FL250 track direct DROGO`

I have never issued a clearance like that and some contries have made them not available in their regulations. But they do exist in other phases of flight.

Comment: Under FAA rules a conditional LUAW may not be issued, but any other conditional may be: "Pass behind traffic" (on the ground or in the air), "reaching 5000, turn left heading," "At FIXXX descend and maintain," etc.